# How do I align items in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

How do we apply the default alignment classes provided by Ionic2? For example, I want a button to appear on the right side of a card.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let table of tables">
    <ion-card-content>
        Card Text
        <button ion-button>
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon> Add Item
        </button>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Item placement section here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/item/Item/)

You can use `ion-item` to wrap and placement attribute.

for example:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let table of tables">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-item>
        Card Text
        <button item-right ion-button>//item right 
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon> Add Item
        </button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Or you can use [Grid-row ,cols](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid)

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let table of tables">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-row>
         <ion-col width-80>
            Card Text
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col>
        <button ion-button>
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon> Add Item
        </button>
      </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```